# How to integrate ARToolkit SDK with GoogleVR library (GoogleCardboard) in Unity project

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, google-cardboard, virtual-reality, artoolkit

I have been trying to use these two libs in a unity project. But how to set up the stereo camera for the ARToolkit camera? When I use the ARToolkit alone, everything looks fine, but if I use two cameras to represent left eye and right eye, there will be a shift between marker and the object on it. They do not overlap anymore.

Anybody knows how to set it?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you switch to use Vuforia instead. It is easy to setup with Google VR.

If you happen to change your mind to using Vuforia. this is how you want to implement Vuforia with Google VR

follow instruction from this site. And use Technique #2
https://developer.vuforia.com/library/articles/Solution/Integrating-Cardboard-to-the-ARVR-Sample

But first you need to register and learn (very straightforward instructions) on how to use Vuforia.